# How to combine social auth/oauth with django custom user model

Tags: django, oauth, django-allauth, social-auth-app-django

I have a custom user model that is based on `AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin` and I would love to use a package such as [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) and/or [social-auth-app-django](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django). I have done some research but did not find any tutorials or examples. Can somebody recommend anything?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the User model for the social auth package in your settings.py. For example:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app.YourCustomUser'
```

Read more about it here: https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/settings.html#user-model